# Yii index removal - what am I missing?

Tags: yii

Here's my setup:

**config.php**

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
          'urlFormat'=>'path',
          'rules'=>array(
           '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
          ),
          'showScriptName'=>false,
 ),
```

**.htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
#+FollowSymLinks must be enabled for any rules to work, this is a security
#requirement of the rewrite engine. Normally it's enabled in the root and we
#shouldn't have to add it, but it doesn't hurt to do so.

RewriteEngine on
#Apache scans all incoming URL requests, checks for matches in our
#.htaccess file 
#and rewrites those matching URLs to whatever we specify.

#allow blank referrers.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site.dev [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?dev.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**On layout menus I have this:**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', 
    array('items'=>
        array(
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','A'),
                'url'=>array('/site/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','Q'),
                'url'=>array('rooms/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','G'),
                'url'=>array('gastronomy/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','A'),
                'url'=>array('activity/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','S'),
                'url'=>array('services/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','C'),
                'url'=>array('contacts/index')
            ),
            array(
                'label'=>Yii::t('site','R'),
                'url'=>array('booking/index')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I explicit call index here, because it seems that, calling it explicitly is required.

With this setup, each time I click on those links I get, for example:

http://site.dev/rooms/index

While I wish to get:

http://site.dev/rooms/

W/out the index name.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is difference between index entry file and default action. You're messing those things.
If you make `'showScriptName'=>true` you will see, that your links will be changed to something like `/index.php/rooms/index` where `index.php` is the index entry file.

As you see with option `'showScriptName'=>false` you don't have that `index.php` in your links, that means that you successfully removed entry script from links.

Now your `room/index` is `controller/action` part of URL route. `room` is controller and `index` is action.
To see `http://site.dev/rooms/` instead of `http://site.dev/rooms/index` you have to edit your URL routes like that:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
    ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

Notice the line `'<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index'` i added. That makes default action `index` to create `controller` route instead of `controller/index`.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to explain this. No luck however. Do we really need that new added line ? Doesn't Yii defines index has a default controller by default ? - I mean, I've added that line, but I still see index on the URL like before. :(

Comment: @MEM same order as i showed you? Order is important in rules. Default action in controllers works for calls, but not for URL generation. The URL rules configuration should work 100% if you don't have something weird somewhere else.

Comment: Could this be Localhost MAMP related ? :/, I believe if I do on menu `'url'=>array('/site')` instead of `'url'=>array('/site/index')`it will work. But I believe that's not the proper way for doing it... :(

Comment: @MEM try change `showScriptName` to `true` and see if links change. I suspect that your configuration doesn't apply somewhy.

Comment: It has been overwritten with another rule. All perfectly working fine now. :) Thanks a lot!